# How to determine succession laws of one’s neighbours?

Tags: crusader-kings, deus-vult

I am playing Crusader Kings Complete (Steam version of original game with Deus Vult expansion) without any mods. I am trying to figure out how to find succession laws in other lands, so that I can marry my daughters off somewhere with matrilineal succession in hope of snatching some titles instead of merely letting others into my dynasty.

I had found that in Crusader Kings 2 it is possible to mouse-over the lord of any land and see their laws, but that does not work in CK 1. Is there any clear note of these laws anywhere in the game? Alternatively, is it possible to see if matrilineal succession is in place by examining the list of heirs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see inheritance laws enacted by various domains, click on own shield to access country information screen, then click on regalia (sceptre and orb) to access laws screen. Then, the list of laws appears. Selecting a law from the list not only provides the description, and opportunity to enact that law, but also highlights on the map counties where same law is in effect in the same way that advances are highlighted.

As far as matrilineal succession goes, I reckon first installment of Crusader Kings does not have this option. Amongst available inheritance laws several allow for tracing inheritance through female members of the family (semisalic variants, and elective law), but none of them provide for switching inheritance to the dynasty of the in-laws.